# Timezone not correct even after setting php.ini

Tags: drupal, timezone

Timezone difference cause my civicrm site showing wrong membership date.

For example:

- Payment Date: Today 10am
- Membership start date: Yesterday

I made below timezone setting in drupal (admin/config/regional/settings):

- Default Timezone: Asia Kuala Lumpur
- Uncheck tick box of  "Users may set their own time zone"

In php.ini, I added below line:

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"
```

But the timezone problem still occurs. Am I missing any configuration? Or is there any place I can force timezone to be Asia/Kuala_Lumpur ?

Comment: any solutions to above problem @vences. Facing the same